# OpenSwoole communicate with server from outside of the server

Tags: php, websocket, process, swoole, openswoole

I created custom WebSocket with OpenSwoole & Laravel. The problem is I can't send data to the server in a convinient way. I want to send data between two seperate PHP processes.

Currently I'm creating a new WebSocket client, connecting to server than sending what I want from there. I know redis pub/sub but I got to do this with only PHP. Is there a way to do this? I searched trough documentation but couldn't find a thing.